# Force footer to stick at the bottom of rendered pages

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Hey I try to force footer to move at the bottom of the page as the content is added.
Similar to : http://jsfiddle.net/eTwJh/2/
. I'm using asp.net mvc with Layout page, where views are rendered as Layout page 'body' with @RenderBody().

P.S. Using position: relative for both footer and body-content now force footer to stay at the bottom of the page, but now hen page is opened, footer is at the half of the page (end of html) min-height: 100% on body element don't seem to have any effect..

Screenshoot: [Footer not staying at the bottom of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KU2rZ.jpg)

Chrome Inspect Element: http:// imgur.com/BWuFxn2

Here is my code Layout.cshtml page:

```
 <body>
 ....
 <div class="container body-content" style="position:relative">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
<footer>
    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year Some Text</p>
</footer>

@if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
<!-- BEGIN # MODAL LOGIN -->
<div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" id="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END # MODAL LOGIN -->
}
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
footer {
  clear: both;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5c5c5c;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

footer p {
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: If there is content **below** the footer, I'd say that you are rendering html below the footer. Open up chrome dev tools and check that

Comment: The fiddle you provided looking fine. Just because of padding and height it is taking that much size.

Comment: move the `modal` before the footer

Comment: Hey @jamiedanq I commented out Modal,  is the same..

Comment: Use only `position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;` for `<footer>` tag.

Comment: @Asif Hey I updated the topic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure both your body-content and footer classes have position set to relative. In the fiddle it's set to absolute because footer is inside wrapper and bottom: 0 pushes it to the bottom of that wrapper.

Or simply create a wrapper for these two divs like in provided fiddle.

Comment: <div class="container body-content" style="position:relative">
    @RenderBody()
</div> This is the wrapper for any View, Html is rendered inside this div.

Comment: But your footer is outside that div, either place it inside it or use position: relative for it.

Comment: And should remain outside, this is the purpose of Layout page, it contains common html for all pages, specific views are rendered in above div..

Comment: Then give it a position: relative instead of absolute if you want it to be beneath your content, can you actually read?

Comment: If I use position: relative for both footer and body-content, when I open the page, footer will be at half of the page (that much content goes), then when content is added it will go down.

Comment: Try another approach - give your body min-height: 100% and make your footer position: absolute and bottom: 0.

Comment: With your last purpose Footer will have fixed position in centre of the page while scrolling, why is css so hard lol..

Comment: Is the new content that you're adding with asp.net stretching it's parent div?

Comment: I have a <div class="container body-content" style="position:relative"> in Layout page. Inside that div I render <div class="jumbotron"> which appear when page is loaded, after a button click, a list of <li> is added to a  <div class="container"> element bellow jumbotron. I observed that using 'relative' for both body-content and footer, when inspecting in chrome there is no html bellow footer so technically footer is at the bottom of html but in the middle of the page..

Comment: It's because middle of the screen appears to be the bottom of the actual page, I don't really understand why - it's hard to tell if you cant debug it with dev tools

Comment: You can try setting it's height to 100vh